# MatLab: Error handling of integer input

Tags: matlab, error-handling, try-catch, user-input, validation

How do I in MatLab catch the error that occours when the user enters letters and other things that aren't numbers in the input:

```
width = input('Enter a width: ');
```

I have played around for a while with the `try/catch` command:

```
width = 0;
message = '';

% Prompting.
while strcmp(message,'Invalid.') || width < 1 || width ~= int32(width)

  try
     disp(message)
     width = input('Frame width: ');
  catch error
     message = 'Invalid.';
  end

end
```

But with no luck (the above doesn't work). As shown I would like a simple message like "Frame width: " for the user the first time he has to enter his choice. But if an error is caught I want the message for him to be "Invalid. Try again: " fx everytime an error occours.

I have also tried the `error()` but I don't know how to place that correctly. Since the `error()` doesn't take the `input` command, where the error happends, as an argument, it must detect it in another way, which I can't figure.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
answer = input('Frame width: ', 's');
[width, status] = str2num(answer);
while ~status || ~isscalar(width) || width ~= floor(width)
  answer = input('Invalid. Try again: ', 's');
  [width, status] = str2num(answer);
end
disp(width);
```

(`status` is 0 if the conversion failed. Without the `isscalar` test, an input like [1 2; 3 4] would also be accepted. The last test ensures that width must be an integer.)

Comment: You may also want to make sure that fractional parts aren't allowed (the title suggests integer inputs are desired).

Comment: Unfortunately I need to avoid using the `'s'` argument in the `input()` command. I am looking for a solution to catch the error when this argument is not used.

Comment: Interesting. Why do you need to avoid the 's'? It's needed to handle the input as a string. It's a usual practice to receive user input as a string, and try to convert it and check the result of conversion in a second step.

Comment: I have to give in it seems. I am convinced. Your answer did the trick, when the `'s'` couldn't be avoided.

Answer (score 4):

```
width = input('Frame width: ');
while(~isInt(width))
    width = input('Invalid. Try again: ');
end
```

and you'll have to have the following function somewhere (or another implementation of it)

```
function retval = isInt(val)
    retval = isscalar(val) && isnumeric(val) && isreal(val) && isfinite(val) && (val == fix(val));
end
```

Comment: +1. I'd note that you could just toss an `isscalar` in there rather than the `if/else` statement.

Comment: It doesn't work when I enter a letter...
The error happens at the line with `width = input('Frame width: ');`. It seems that when a letter (or any string) is entered, an error happens here because the `input()` did not ask for a string. Then the program never reaches the `while` loop. Instead it breaks at this line.

Comment: @Steeven If you enter a string with `' '` around it, what happens?  If you don't enclose the string, it will think you're trying to enter a variable from the workspace and evaluates that variable. If an error occurs, it should just prompt again though rather than breaking entirely

Comment: So, if I want to avoid the `'s'` argument to the `input()`, I have to add apostrophes around the input string? That wouldn't be user friendly for the user. Is it then not possible to catch the error that occours because a string is sent?

Comment: only apostrophes for strings, just like in your normal code: `4` is integer, `4.5` is double, `a` is a variable, `'b'` is a string. You can always use the `'s'` parameter to define that your input is _always_ a string.. but since you're avoiding that, I guess we're stuck..

Comment: The error you're seeing isn't because the input is a string.  Rather, if you type some text, matlab tries to find a function or variable of that name and evaluate it.  This can actually be quite handy if you think about it: perhaps some high-precision number is stored in a variable already and you want to use that as input.  In that case you can just type the variable name, with no apostrophes, and the value of the variable is used as the input. `input()` should handle an error of this kind automatically though without crashing your script.

Comment: Okay... The user would then be able to send in another of my already established variables to the input. Not good I see. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanations. When the `'s'` can't be avoided (because I can't be sure there will not be entered any letters) I see @kol's answer as the simplest and most straight forward. Thanks for your time and a nice int-checking script.